# ListView inside ViewPager - Items in ListView keep blank

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I'm facing a very strange phenomenon. I'm using a ViewPager from the compatibility package to display profiles.

Every profile is just a ListView with custom elements in it. Every element has two states:

1. There is data - display it
2. There's no data - display place holder

Every time I swipe between profiles I reset the data within the item objects. When I remove the REST-Calls and just let the profile item empty - which should display the placeholder - all items keep blank.

What could be the problem?

EDIT:/

That's how I set the current item in the listview. The PageViewAdapter seems to be OK, if I use static content everything works perfect.

```
    final TextView lblTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblTitle);
    final LinearLayout llContent = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContent);
    final ProfileItem item = getItem(userPosition);


    String title = item.getTitle();
    if(title == null || title.equals("")) {
        lblTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        lblTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    }

    if(item.getContent().getParent() != null) {
        ((ViewGroup)item.getContent().getParent()).removeAllViews();
    }

    llContent.removeAllViews();
    llContent.addView(item.getContent());
```

The Items look all very similar like that:

```
@Override
public View getContent() {
    if(isTextEmpty()) {
        return noTextTherePlaceholder;
    } else {
        return view;
    }
}
```

The effect keeps the same even if I return just view or noTextTherePlaceholder.

If I would instate new views like a TextView in the getView method everything works as expected.

Comment: You should have shown us some code, can't see it from here. Your ViewPager adapter's code is of particular interest.

Answer (score 0):

With view pager you have to get all your data in your `Activity.onCreate` and then use that data in your ViewPagers adapter's `onInstantiateItem`.

Comment: That's not true. You can edit the content whenever you want, you just have to obtain the correct view reference to call invalidate when something changed.

Comment: Sure, what I meant was your data should be persisted somehow in your activity object. Still waiting for your instantiating code though.

Comment: That's not possible because I have to fetch it via REST the first time. It would be very nasty if the app would have to wait for finishing the call before showing the next page. Code is delivered.